# Initialize service data with ajax request using promise?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a service that will hold the shopping cart content of my website using AngularJS. I will then use this to make sure the reference to the cart in all controllers etc should be to the same object and synced.

The problem is that the cart content must be initialized via an ajax call. My code below does not work but it shows what I'm trying to accomplish. I would like to somehow get the list of items and return with getItems(), but if the list of items is not yet fetched then I will need to fetch for it first and promise a return. I'm trying to wrap my head around the "promise" concept but so far I have not fully got it yet.

```
factory('cartFactory', function ($rootScope, Restangular) {
    var cart = $rootScope.cart = {};

    return {
        getItems: function () {
            if (undefined == cart.items) {
                return Restangular.oneUrl('my.api.cart.show', Routing.generate('en__RG__my.api.cart.show')).get().then(function($cart){
                    cart = $rootScope.cart = $cart;

                    angular.forEach(cart.items, function(value, key){
                        cart.items[key]['path'] = Routing.generate('en__RG__my.frontend.product.info', {'slug': value.variant.product.slug});
                    });

                    return cart.items;
                });
            } else {
                return cart.items
            }
        },
        setItems: function ($items) {
            cart.items = $items;
        },
        removeItem: function ($item) {
            cart.splice(cart.indexOf($item), 1);
        },
        addItem: function ($item) {
            cart.items.push($item)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain this in a very simplified way.

A promises is just an object that is "passed around" and we use this objects to attach functions that will be executed whenever we resolve, reject or notify the promise.

Because in Javascript objects are passed by reference we are able to refer to the same object in several places, in our case inside the service and the controller.

In our service we execute:

```
getItems: function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // do async stuff

    return deferred.promise; 
}
```

Lets say that the variable deferred above is an object more os less like this:

```
{
  reject: function (reason) {
      this.errorCallback(reason);
  },
  resolve: function (val) {
      this.successCallback(val);
  },
  notify: function (value) {
      this.notifyCallback(value);
  },
  promise: {
      then: function (successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) {
          this. successCallback = successCallback;
          this.errorCallback = errorCallback;
          this.notifyCallback = notifyCallback;
      }
  }
}
```

So when we call getItems() a promise (deferred.promise) is returned and this allows the callee to set the callbacks to be executed whenever the promise changes its state (resolve, reject or notify).

So inside our controller I am setting only the resolve callback, if the promises is rejected it will happen silently because there is no errorCallback to be executed.

```
cartFactory.getItems().then(function (items) {
    $scope.items = items;
});
```

Of course there is much more behind it, but I think this simplistic promise will help you get the basic idea. Be aware that cartFactory.getItems() must always return a promise, even when the items are already loaded, otherwise cartFactory.getItems().then() would break if , for example, you return an array.

[Here a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iwewub/116/edit) with your cartFactory service, I am using $timeout to simulate an async call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, thank you very much Bertrand, really appreciate your sample code.